# Sorting a vector of a class

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I have class called "UltrasoundTemplate". These UltrasoundTemplate objects contain an int parameter, which shows when they where defined (something like a time stamp). And I have a class called "UltrasoundTarget" which contains a vector of UltrasoundTemplate's. 
I add UltrasoundTemplates to the vector with push_back(ultrasoundTemplate).

Now I want to sort the vector by the order of time stamps instead of the order I added them to the vector.

I found a lot of answers in google, which all show me the same solution, but obviously I'm still doing something wrong. Here are the code snippets I think are necessary for finding a solution:

ultrasoundTemplate.h

```
class UltrasoundTemplate
{
public:
 UltrasoundTemplate(/*...*/);
 int getVolumePos() { return volume_; }
private:
 int volume_;
};
```

ultrasoundTarget.h

```
//the sort algorithm
struct MyTemplateSort {
bool operator() ( UltrasoundTemplate t1, UltrasoundTemplate t2){
    int it1 = t1.getVolumePos();
    int it2 = t2.getVolumePos();

    if (it1 < it2)
        return true;
    return false;
}
};

class UltrasoundTarget
{
public:
 UltrasoundTarget(/*...*/);
 vector<UltrasoundTemplate> getTemplates() { return USTemplateVector_; }
private:
 vector<UltrasoundTemplate> USTemplateVector_;
};
```

FMainWindow.cpp

```
void FMainWindow::match_slot()
{
 int i;
 //here I get the name of the target I'm looking for
 QTreeWidgetItem *item = targetInfoWidget_->treeWidget->currentItem();
 int index = targetInfoWidget_->treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
 QString itemToAppendName = item->text(0);
 for(i = 0; i < USTargetVector.size(); i++){
  if(USTargetVector.at(i).getName() == itemToAppendName) {
   //here I try to sort
   MyTemplateSort tmpltSrt;
   std::sort(USTargetVector.at(i).getTemplates().begin(),
              USTargetVector.at(i).getTemplates().end(), tmpltSrt);     
   break;
  }
 }
```

As an example: I define Template1 in Volume(0), Template2 in Volume(70) and Template3 in Volume(40). The order now is (Template1, Template2, Template3) but I want it to be (Template1, Template3, Template2). But this code is not doing it.

If there's Information missing, just tell me and I'll provide more code.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Did you forget to assign `volume_`, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Your `getTemplates()` method returns by value, making a mess here:

```
std::sort(USTargetVector.at(i).getTemplates().begin(),
          USTargetVector.at(i).getTemplates().end(), tmpltSrt);
```

You are sorting an incompatible iterator range. You can fix that particular problem by returning a reference:

```
vector<UltrasoundTemplate>& getTemplates() { return USTemplateVector_; }
```

It is common practice to add a `const` overload to such a method:

```
const vector<UltrasoundTemplate>& getTemplates() const { return USTemplateVector_; }
```

You can also modify your comparison functor to avoid unnecessary copies (and for general readability and const correctness):

```
struct MyTemplateSort {
  bool operator() const ( const UltrasoundTemplate& t1, const UltrasoundTemplate& t2)
  {
    return t1.getVolumePos() < t2.getVolumePos();
  }
};
```

This will require that you make `getVolumePos()` a `const` method, which it should be anyway:

```
class UltrasoundTemplate
{
public:
 ...
 int getVolumePos() const { return volume_; }
 ...
};
```

Note that is is not generally good practice to provide references to the private data of a class. If possible, you should find a way to remove that from the `UltraSoundTarget` interface. You could, for instance, expose a pair of iterators, and/or give the class a sort method.

Comment: I think you have touched in too many topics in a single answer! If him intends to change the content of UltrasoundTarget, him shouldn't be using the const & version of getTemplates, because the content of a const reference can't change.

Comment: Yeah, i see that. +1 to the answer, btw. Nice writeup.

Comment: @IanMedeiros They wouldn't use the `const` overload, but it is good to have one for the cases where it is needed.

Comment: Since the templates vector is encapsulated in the target class, it would also make more sense to have a sort method added to the target class instead of doing it outside the class ... which would have avoided his return-by-value vs return-by-reference issue.

Comment: @ZacHowland Yes, I agree. I may add a note about that.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I get that. But if him implemented just the const& version, him would get a compilation time error that can mess with his head.

Comment: @IanMedeiros of course. And they might learn something in the process. But I suggested adding both overloads.

Answer (score 0):

juanchopanza answer is correct, the problem is the way you are returning the vector from UltrasoundTarget. Just to touch another topic, maybe it would be nice to change a little the designing of your implementation. As UltrasoundTarget is a container of Ultrasound's, it makes sense to implement the sort as a method of this class, this way you have direct access to USTemplateVector_ and will save unecessary copies. Something like:

```
class UltrasoundTarget
{
public:
 UltrasoundTarget(/*...*/);
 vector<UltrasoundTemplate> getTemplates() { return USTemplateVector_; }

 void sort();

private:
 vector<UltrasoundTemplate> USTemplateVector_;
};

void UltrasoundTarget::sort()
{
 std::sort(USTemplateVector_.begin(), USTemplateVector_.end(), tmpltSrt);  
}

void FMainWindow::match_slot()
{
 int i;
 //here I get the name of the target I'm looking for
 QTreeWidgetItem *item = targetInfoWidget_->treeWidget->currentItem();
 int index = targetInfoWidget_->treeWidget->indexOfTopLevelItem(item);
 QString itemToAppendName = item->text(0);
 for(i = 0; i < USTargetVector.size(); i++){
 if(USTargetVector.at(i).getName() == itemToAppendName) 
 {
   //here I try to sort
   MyTemplateSort tmpltSrt;
   USTargetVector.at(i).sort(); 
   break;
 }
}
```